# langchain: how to use a custom deployed fastAPI embedding model locally?

Tags: python, python-requests, langchain

I want to build a retriever in Langchain and want to use an already deployed fastAPI embedding model. How could I do that?

```python
from langchain_community.vectorstores import DocArrayInMemorySearch

embeddings_model = requests.post("http://internal-server/embeddings/")

db = DocArrayInMemorySearch.from_documents(chunked_docs, embeddings_model)
retriever = db.as_retriever()
```

Comment: To clarify, does the POST API generate embedding vectors (a matrix of float values)?

Comment: Yes, a list with float values

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom embeddings class that subclasses the `BaseModel` and `Embeddings` classes. Example:

```py
from typing import List

import requests
from langchain_core.embeddings import Embeddings
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel


class APIEmbeddings(BaseModel, Embeddings):
    """Calls an API to generate embeddings."""

    def embed_documents(self, texts: List[str]) -> List[List[float]]:
        # TODO: Call API to generate embeddings
        # requests.post("http://internal-server/embeddings/")
        pass

    def embed_query(self, text: str) -> List[float]:
        # TODO: Call API to generate embeddings
        # requests.post("http://internal-server/embeddings/")
        pass
```

`embed_documents()` and `embed_query()` are abstract methods in the `Embeddings` class and they must be implemented. The [`OllamaEmbeddings`](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.13/libs/community/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py) class is a simple example of how to create a custom embeddings class.

You can use the custom embeddings class just like any other embeddings class.

```py
embeddings_model = APIEmbeddings()

db = DocArrayInMemorySearch.from_documents(chunked_docs, embeddings_model)
retriever = db.as_retriever()
```

References

1. [Embeddings (LangChain GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.13/libs/core/langchain_core/embeddings/embeddings.py)
2. [Ollama (LangChain GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.13/libs/community/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py)